# Downloading excel in automation script , but where it will be download when running in azure devops pipeline?

Tags: azure, devops

In my automation script, I am downloading an excel from google chrome, but when running the same script in the azure DevOps pipeline, it's not downloading the excel.

Answer (score 0):

Review the logs of your ADO pipeline task--you should see more details about why the file download step fails. It may be that ADO Pipelines is missing the authentication credentials required to access the file (for example, Chrome is already logged in to your Google account). To fix this, either change the file permissions to allow anonymous access or research how to authenticate your request to download the file.